# Avoid adding duplicates in SQLServer while importing a CSV file using C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

So, I have a table called Curr. My primary key is CurrID (auto-increment) and I have Foreign Key CouID. My csv file looks like this:

```
|1|12345| 
|2|23456|
```

Everytime I add values to my csv file, I will upload it in the database. Ex:

```
|1|12345| 
|2|23456| 
|3|12345|
|4|93821|
```

Now the problem is that I don't want it to be added because it's already in the database. The database should look like this:

```
|1|12345| 
|2|23456| 
|4|93821|
```

Please help me. Here's my code.

```
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(Curr_Upload.PostedFile.FileName);
    Curr_Upload.SaveAs(csvPath);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] {new DataColumn("CurrID", typeof(int)) 
            new DataColumn("CouID", typeof(int)) });


    string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
    foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                lbl_status.Text = row;
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;

            }
        }
    }


    using (connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(constring))
        {
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Curr";
            connection.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using unique indices? Is that an option?

Comment: One option is to BULK INSERT into temp table and then insert filtered data into actual table.

Comment: I'm new to C# someone please tell me how to use BULK INSERT?